# Rss feeds and pdf files in a Js custom Media Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, rss, media-player

I'm working on a custom media player for a website a and i'm trying to figure how to add compatibility for image and pdf files and also for having a streaming live webpage.

Actually it is the user that creates a playlist with a drag and drop system and we would like to create the same thing for a images and live webpages (rss feeds)

Do you guys have any idea how this could be done ?

Comment: What would be perfect is that the image files convert to a video file that becomes a slideshow.

Comment: That would be a great but how can you do that with a URL ?

Comment: To be more precise I'm looking in to monitoring a client's own webpage in the video player so that he can display it in his store.